# arm64 flag like arc flag (-fno-objc-arc)

Tags: ios, 64-bit, compiler-flags, arm64

is there a opportunity to set a flag for specific files like the arc flag (-fno-objc-arc) in the compiler settings to use the 32bit lib instead of the 64bit lib?

The thing is, that I use a class with some functions they doesn't work in 64bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no source file-specific flag for specifying the bit architecture like you find with `-fno-objc-arc`.

This is because you cannot have a single program compiled partially for 32bit and partially for 64bit architectures, so you can't enable or disable this on a per source file basis like you could with `-fno-objc-arc`.

Comment: @Eike if you think this is the right answer please accept the answer to complete the question